# call jQuery twice

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery code inside content(div) is already loaded by jQuery, here is my example code:

```
<!-- Slide Panel with Form Adding data  -->
<div style="display: none;" id="slideAddForm" >
<h2>Add Row</h2>
from here ..
</div>

<div class="tabs"> <!-- Tabs -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#first"> First </a></li>
        <li><a  class="secondA" href="#second"> Second </a></li>
        <li><a  class="comments_title" href="#third"> Third </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- first tab .. html data -->
<div id="first">
<a class="bAddRow" href="#"> Add Row  </a>   <!-- To show slideAddForm div .. it`s work OK  -->
anything here ..
</div>

<!-- second tab and 3rd tab get data from server -->
<div id="second">
  <!-- load page in this tab  -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.secondA").click(function(){
      $("#second").load("server.php");
      });
      });
  </script>
</div>

<div id="third"></div>
```

Now in server.php I put this:

```
<a class="bAddRow" href="#"> Add Row  </a>  <!-- not work !  -->
```

But it does not work ..

You can see, in the first tab the link (Add Row) work fine, but it does not work in the (#second) tab
because (I think) it is loaded already by ajax.

Don't say put this line

```
<a class="bAddRow" href="#"> Add Row  </a>
```

after

```
<div id="second">
```

and before javascript code, because this is a simple code to clear my problem.
My really code is complicated, and I have to put (for example) this line (add Row link) in the Server.php and I want it to show slideAddForm div

Any help?

Comment: I've taken a guess at what I think is going on and how to fix it. But to know for sure, you'll have to post the code that shows your slideAddForm div.

Answer (score 2):

You must be binding code to show the `slideAddForm` div to `.bAddRow` somewhere, right? Maybe something like this?

```
$('.bAddRow').bind('click', function() {
    $('slideAddForm').show();
}
```

To bind current and future matched elements, use the `live` method to bind the event instead:

```
$('.bAddRow').live('click', function() {
    $('slideAddForm').show();
}
```

(And make sure to read [the jQuery documentation for the method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn), since there are a few differences from bind.)

Answer (score 0):

Just call it again.

```
function loader(){
    $("#second").load("server.php");
    clickmaker();
});

function clickmaker() {
    $("a.secondA").click(loader);
}

$(document).ready(clickmaker());
```

Answer (score 0):

What function do you call when you click on bAddRow? Also, are you  trying to say, you just want to reattach click event to bAddRow when panel is laoded? If so, this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RowAdder = {

   //Initialize
   Init: function() {
      $("a.secondA").click(function() {
         $("#second").load("server.php", function() {
             RowAdder.Attach();     
         });
      });
   },

   //Reattach events
   Attach: function() {
       $(".bAddRow").click(function(){
           //ADD EVENTS BEHIND bAddRow CLICK HERE
       });
   },
};

//Initialize script
$(document).ready(function(){
    RowAdder.Init();
});
</script>
```